# Floating action button are not aligned properly in Jelly bean (API 18), working fine 18 and above

Tags: floating-action-button

I created layout with floating action button. There is one floating action button (called filter) by which i show up two other FABs. 
Issue is about space between FABs. Gap is showing more in API level 18 and below.
Layout is working good in API level 19 and above but it is not showing properly in below 19, there is too much gap between floating action button, not sure what is issue here. Please let me know if i need spacial handling for 18 and below.

[image: Here is Screenshot and xml]

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bottom_bar_color"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.stylzq.widget.StylzQRecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/images_data_list_frag_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/go_to_top_fab"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/go_to_top"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="190dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_home_lyt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_6"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_text_background"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_3"
                android:text="  Home "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_home_api"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_6"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
                app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/celebs_lyt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_6"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/celeb_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_text_background"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_3"
                android:text=" Celebrity "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/celebs_api_fab"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_celeb"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
                app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/popular_lyt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_6"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_text_background"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_3"
                android:text="  Popular  "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/popular_api_fab"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_popular"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
                app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/api_filter_fab"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />
</RelativeLayout>
```